# Is this proof of a subspace property correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

The question states:

> Prove that if $S\subseteq T \subseteq V$ and if $T$ is a subspace of $V$, then $L(S)\subseteq T$.

My proof is as follows:

All elements in $S$ are in $T$. Now $T$ is a subspace, $\therefore$ all elements in $S$ spanning $L(S)$ are independent elements in $T$.
$\therefore T$ is spanned by $S$ if $\dim T = n$ and there are $n$ elements in $S$; or $T$ is spanned by a set $Q$ containing all independent elements in $S$.
In both cases, the independent elements in $S$ (which span $L(S)$) form part of a basis for $T$.
$\therefore L(S) \subseteq T$.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming $V$ is finite-dimensional.

$S$ can be a large set, possibly infinite. You seem to imply that $S$ consists only of linearly independent elements, or that it has equal cardinality to its basis.

Your argument can be better phrased like this: Let $\{x_1, \ldots x_n\}$ be a basis for $S$. You correctly state that $S$ spans $T$ if and only if $\dim T = n$.

In any case, $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ is a linearly independent set in $T$ so there exists a basis $Q$ for $T$ which contains $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$. Hence every linear combination of $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ is in fact a linear combination of elements of $Q$, and hence belongs to $T$.

Therefore $L(S) \subseteq T$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $ S \subseteq T$ , we have $L(S) \subseteq L(T)$. Since $T$ is a supspace of $V$, we get $T=L(T).$ Hence $L(S) \subseteq T.$

Comment: Is the proof that I wrote correct though?

Answer (score 1):

Let $v\in L(S)$ then there exists $v_1,\dots , v_n\in S$ and $a_1,\dots , a_n\in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$v=\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i$

But $v_i\in S\subseteq T$ and $T$ is a subspace so each linear combination of element of $T$ is in $T$ then

$v\in T$ so $L(S)\subseteq T$

Comment: Thanks. Was my proof flawed?

Comment: @JohnArg i don’t understand what means for you that all elements of S are independent elements in T

Comment: I mean that all the elements in a basis for $L(S)$ are also at least part of elements of a basis for $T$.

Comment: It is not true in general.. for example you can have an infinite set S while T is finite dimensional . In this case S it is not a subset of a base of T

Comment: But we are given that $S$ is a subset of $T$. Then if $T$ is finite dimensional, wouldn't $S$ have to be finite-dimensional as well?

Comment: @JohnArg Simpler: if $S=\{(1\ 1), (2\ 2)\}$ and $T=\mathbb{R}^2$, then $(1\ 1)$ and $(2\ 2)$ are definetely not independent in $T$ since $(2\ 2)=2\cdot (1\ 1)$.

Comment: Ah ok, so you want choose a base of S and complete that base to all T. The problem is that S is not a subspace and does not make sense choose a base of S

Answer (score 0):

First, the span operator is monotonous w.r.t. set inclusion.
That is, if $S,T$ are subsets of a $K$-vector space $V$, then
$$S\subseteq T\Rightarrow L(S)\subseteq L(T).$$

Second, the span operator is idempotent.
That is, if $S$ is a subset of a $K$-vector space $V$, then
$$L(L(S)) =L(S).$$

In particular, if $S$ is a subspace of $V$, then
$$L(S)=S.$$

These properties suffice to prove your claim.